# How can you prove $(P\rightarrow Q)\lor(Q \rightarrow P)$ using natural deduction?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I am a Physics major interested in logic, but I cannot seem to find how to put the rules together for a proof. I am reading a book that uses a tree-style!

Comment: What rules do you have available?

Comment: You say to use natural deduction, but you also mention 'tree-style' ... those are two different techniques. Can you please explain what kinds of rules you have to work with?

Comment: Not provable in natural deduction unless you use the excluded middle.  One of the properties of a normalized natural deduction proof is that every expression in every step of the proof is a subexpression of the consequence or the assumptions.  The final step has to be or-intro, or an elimination step.  So any proof would require an expression that is not a subexpression of $(P \Rightarrow Q) \lor (Q \Rightarrow P)$.